# Manufacturer OUI info only 8 characters long in Network scanner

Tags: python, networking, scapy, mac-address, arp

Good morning. I made a simple network scanner which lists information about scanned devices, however I noticed that the OUI Manufacturer information is only printed as 8 characters long.

What am I missing here?

```
import scapy.all as scapy
import manuf

def get_device_type(mac_address):
    p = manuf.MacParser()
    manufacturer = p.get_manuf(mac_address)
    return manufacturer or "Unknown"


def scan(ip):
    print("Sending ARP requests...")
    arp_request = scapy.ARP(pdst=ip)
    broadcast = scapy.Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")
    arp_request_broadcast = broadcast / arp_request
    answered_list = scapy.srp(arp_request_broadcast, timeout=1, verbose=False)[0]
    
    print("\nIP\t\tMAC Address\t\tManufacturer\t\tOS\n---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    
    for element in answered_list:
        ip = element[1].psrc
        mac = element[1].hwsrc
        device_type = get_device_type(mac)
        try:
            syn_packet = scapy.IP(dst=ip) / scapy.TCP(dport=80, flags="S")
            response = scapy.sr1(syn_packet, timeout=1, verbose=False)
            if response:
                if response.haslayer(scapy.TCP) and response.getlayer(scapy.TCP).flags == 0x12:
                    os_info = "Linux/Unix"
                elif response.haslayer(scapy.TCP) and response.getlayer(scapy.TCP).flags == 0x14:
                    os_info = "Windows"
                else:
                    os_info = "Unknown"
            else:
                os_info = "Unknown"
        except:
            os_info = "Error"
        print(f"{ip}\t{mac}\t{device_type}\t{os_info}\t")
    print("\nDone\n---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")

scan("192.168.42.1/24")
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_manuf` returns the abbreviated 8 character name from the Wireshark database. To get the full name, use `get_manuf_long`.

Comment: OH ok lol, this worked. Thank you so much.